# Redirect domain to an URL

Tags: url, redirect, domain-name

I own some domain website.com. Is there a way to redirect this domain to an URL 'test.com/test'?

I have tried to redirect via a script or .htaccess on a hosting, however, looking how to do it configuring the domain, without a hosting.

Comment: You need to redirect to another url the user, right? have you tried with an `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @dwpu I don't want to use a hosting

Comment: What do you mean with I don't want to use a hosting?

Comment: You can try by setting the DNS, if your hosting provider give you this possibility

Comment: @dwpu I mean, I don't have a hosting to set an .htaccess